# I am getting this error while creating build using jenkins. Can some one help me with this

Tags: maven, jenkins

message :

> Failed to execute goal on project mw-platform-common: Could not
>   resolve dependencies for project
>   com.meltwater.platform:mw-platform-common:jar:1.0.0: The following
>   artifacts could not be resolved:
>   org.apache.hbase:hbase-core:jar:0.20.5,
>   net.sf.katta:katta-core:jar:0.6.1: Could not find artifact
>   org.apache.hbase:hbase-core:jar:0.20.5 in ibiblio mirror
>   (http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2) cause : Could not
>   resolve dependencies for project
>   com.meltwater.platform:mw-platform-common:jar:1.0.0: The following
>   artifacts could not be resolved:
>   org.apache.hbase:hbase-core:jar:0.20.5,
>   net.sf.katta:katta-core:jar:0.6.1: Could not find artifact
>   org.apache.hbase:hbase-core:jar:0.20.5 in ibiblio mirror
>   (http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2)

Stack trace :

> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal on project mw-platform-common: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project
>   com.meltwater.platform:mw-platform-common:jar:1.0.0: The following
>   artifacts could not be resolved:
>   org.apache.hbase:hbase-core:jar:0.20.5,
>   net.sf.katta:katta-core:jar:0.6.1: Could not find artifact
>   org.apache.hbase:hbase-core:jar:0.20.5 in ibiblio mirror
>   (http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2)

Comment: Can you build this localy in your IDE or via the command line?

Comment: yes i can build this locally via command line, it's just that when i checkout using git and do a build with jenkins, i am facing this problem

Comment: so did you eventually install hbase-core 0.20.5 manually to your local repository?

Answer (score 3):

The dependency you are using is not located in the mirror. The folder on the mirror url is empty http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/apache/hbase/

Try using another mirror.

EDIT: I found the 21-SNAPSHOT Version in the apache maven repo: https://repository.apache.org/

Comment: how do i replace the mirror. I meant which file i need to modify to point to this mirror.

Comment: try this: [guide-mirror-settings](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html) and remember to change the version of hbase-core in your pom if you try to use the apache repository. The apache repository only contains version 0.21.0-SNAPSHOT.